# Play Framework: CSS files not working on Heroku

Tags: css, heroku, playframework, sbt

In CSS I'm trying to increase the font of text.

Output:

On Localhost[image]

However, when deploying on Heroku, following is the output.

[image]

**main.scala.html**

```
@*
* This template is called from the `index` template. This template
* handles the rendering of the page header and body tags. It takes
* two arguments, a `String` for the title of the page and an `Html`
* object to insert into the body of the page.
*@
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @* Here's where we render the page title `String`. *@
    <title>@title</title>
    <h1>Testing</h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
</head>
<body>
    @* And here's where we render the `Html` object containing
     * the page content. *@
    @content

    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

`h1 { font-size: 5em }`

**routes**

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

#GET     /public/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

POST     /downloadreceipt               controllers.HomeController.downloadReceipt

GET     /displayreceipt                 controllers.HomeController.displayReceipt
```

Deploy method:
`sbt stage deployHeroku`

Comment: How are you running on localhost? Try `sbt stage` and then `./target/universal/stage/bin/yourappname` to see if you can reproduce. I suspect the CSS file is in your src dir only.

Comment: On localhost, I'm running using `sbt run`. BTW, I got the solution, `sbt stage clean` & `sbt stage deployHeroku` worked. :)

Comment: Moreover, I'm using , `play-pdf`, https://github.com/benjohnde/play-pdf/blob/ad3d0af871b94cebcc495c923de5b0975267be24/README.md#template-rules, which added to the complication. I had `media=screen` qualifier in the html file due to which the CSS was not working.

Answer (score 0):

h1 { font-size: 5em } should be h1 { font-size: 5em; } - Also, make sure the location to your css file is correct on heroku, you can open developer console and check to see if it has loaded.